# Considerations for Compiling and Parallelizing Code Outside or Inside Map[]

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization, compile, functional-style, map

Assume `f` as well as `Map[f,list]` are parallelizable and compilable, such that parallelization and compilation give significant speedup for both.

What considerations should I make when determining which of the following paradigms is best to use and gives best performance?

---

1. `Map[(*compiled form of f with Parallelization->True*),list]`

(compilation and parallelization inside)

2. `ParallelMap[(*compiled form of f*),list]`

(parallelization outside, compilation inside)

3. compiled form of entire `Map[f,list]` with Parallelization->True

(compilation and parallelization outside)

---

What are general use cases for each of these three paradigms?

Comment: None of them are ideal as all involve the _Mathematica_ kernel. Compile with options `RunTimeAttributes->{Listable}` and `Parallelization->True` and then call `f[list]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In these cases, one typically has to try a variety of things and *measure*.

Here I try to give a simple example:

```
Block[{x, xx, y, yy},
  xx = Table[Compile`GetElement[x, i], {i, 1, 12}];
  
  With[{code = Power[Total[Power[x, 24]], 1/24]},
   
   f = Function @@ {x, code /. Compile`GetElement -> Indexed};
   
   cf = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}},
     code,
     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
     RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
     ];
   
   cpf = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}},
     code,
     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
     Parallelization -> True,
     RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
     ];
   
   ];
  ];
```

Now the test results (from my Intel Haswell 4 Core CPU):

```
n = 100000; X = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 12}];

a1 = Map[f, X]; // AbsoluteTiming // First 

a2 = Map[cf, X]; // AbsoluteTiming // First 

a3 = Map[cpf, X]; // AbsoluteTiming // First

a4 = ParallelMap[f, X]; // AbsoluteTiming // First 

a5 = ParallelMap[cf, X]; // AbsoluteTiming // First 

a6 = ParallelMap[cpf, X]; // AbsoluteTiming // First

a7 = cf[X]; // AbsoluteTiming // First 

a8 = cpf[X]; // AbsoluteTiming // First

a1 == a2 == a3 == a4 == a5 == a6 == a7 == a8
```

> 0.271289
>
> 0.025701
>
> 0.032341
>
> 2.30748
>
> 1.98798
>
> 1.98874
>
> 0.024378
>
> 0.010684
>
> True

As you see, `ParallelMap` is very bad in this case. The major reason is that the loop iterates are just too small to justify the (immense!) overhead of `Parallel`.

We can also see from this that `Parallelization->True` is only active in conjuction with `RunTimeAttributes->{Listable}` and the latter is activle only if the function is called in the `Listable` way.

But with both activated, it is almost as fast as built-in vectorization

```
a9 = Power[Total[Power[X, 24], {2}], 1/24]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
a8 == a9
```

> 0.009269
>
> True

This is a very simple loop and the ratio between memory accesses and floating point operations is really bad. So other loops may behave differently.